# CSS Animation: Need It To Stop On Last Frame/Word

Tags: css, animation

I've added rotating text w/ CSS animation. I want the animation to go through 1 cycle and freeze on the last frame. With my current code, the animation does one cycle and ends on a blank frame. Any suggestions on how to correct this?

```css
    body {} .rw-wrapper {
      width: 80%;
      position: relative;
      margin: 110px auto 0 auto;
      font-family: 'Bree Serif';
      padding: 10px;
    }
    .rw-sentence {
      margin: 0;
      text-align: left;
      text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
    }
    .rw-sentence span {
      color: #444;
      font-size: 200%;
      font-weight: normal;
    }
    .rw-words {
      display: inline;
      text-indent: 10px;
    }
    .rw-words-1 span {
      position: absolute;
      opacity: 0;
      overflow: hidden;
      color: #6b969d;
      -webkit-animation: rotateWord 8s 1 forwards;
      -ms-animation: rotateWord 8s 1 forwards;
      animation: rotateWord 8s 1 forwards;
    }
    .rw-words-1 span:nth-child(2) {
      -webkit-animation-delay: 2s;
      -ms-animation-delay: 2s;
      animation-delay: 2s;
      color: #6b889d;
    }
    .rw-words-1 span:nth-child(3) {
      -webkit-animation-delay: 4s;
      -ms-animation-delay: 4s;
      animation-delay: 4s;
      color: #6b739d;
    }
    .rw-words-1 span:nth-child(4) {
      -webkit-animation-delay: 6s;
      -ms-animation-delay: 6s;
      animation-delay: 6s;
      color: #7a6b9d;
    }
    @-webkit-keyframes rotateWord {
      0% {
        opacity: 0;
      }
      2% {
        opacity: 0;
        -webkit-transform: translateY(-30px);
      }
      5% {
        opacity: 1;
        -webkit-transform: translateY(0px);
      }
      17% {
        opacity: 1;
        -webkit-transform: translateY(0px);
      }
      20% {
        opacity: 0;
        -webkit-transform: translateY(30px);
      }
      80% {
        opacity: 0;
      }
      100% {
        opacity: 0;
      }
    }
    @-ms-keyframes rotateWord {
      0% {
        opacity: 0;
      }
      2% {
        opacity: 0;
        -ms-transform: translateY(-30px);
      }
      5% {
        opacity: 1;
        -ms-transform: translateY(0px);
      }
      17% {
        opacity: 1;
        -ms-transform: translateY(0px);
      }
      20% {
        opacity: 0;
        -ms-transform: translateY(30px);
      }
      80% {
        opacity: 0;
      }
      100% {
        opacity: 0;
      }
    }
    @keyframes rotateWord {
      0% {
        opacity: 0;
      }
      2% {
        opacity: 0;
        -webkit-transform: translateY(-30px);
        transform: translateY(-30px);
      }
      5% {
        opacity: 1;
        -webkit-transform: translateY(0px);
        transform: translateY(0px);
      }
      17% {
        opacity: 1;
        -webkit-transform: translateY(0px);
        transform: translateY(0px);
      }
      20% {
        opacity: 0;
        -webkit-transform: translateY(30px);
        transform: translateY(30px);
      }
      80% {
        opacity: 0;
      }
      100% {
        opacity: 0;
      }
    }
    @media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
      .rw-sentence {
        font-size: 18px;
      }
    }
    @media screen and (max-width: 320px) {
      .rw-sentence {
        font-size: 9px;
      }
    }
```

```html
<section class="rw-wrapper">
  <h2 class="rw-sentence">
      <span>Test</span>
      <div class="rw-words rw-words-1">
       <span>one</span>
       <span>two</span>
       <span>three</span>
       <span>four</span>
      </div>
     </h2>
</section>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You keyframe at 100% has opacity zero. You can write a separate animation for the last work and use that instead.

Like this (I didn't add vendor-specific keyframes, just `@keyframes rotateLastWord`, but you can add them as well):

```css
body {} .rw-wrapper {
      width: 80%;
      position: relative;
      margin: 110px auto 0 auto;
      font-family: 'Bree Serif';
      padding: 10px;
    }
    .rw-sentence {
      margin: 0;
      text-align: left;
      text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
    }
    .rw-sentence span {
      color: #444;
      font-size: 200%;
      font-weight: normal;
    }
    .rw-words {
      display: inline;
      text-indent: 10px;
    }
    .rw-words-1 span {
      position: absolute;
      opacity: 0;
      overflow: hidden;
      color: #6b969d;
      -webkit-animation: rotateWord 8s 1 forwards;
      -ms-animation: rotateWord 8s 1 forwards;
      animation: rotateWord 8s 1 forwards;
    }
    .rw-words-1 span:nth-child(2) {
      -webkit-animation-delay: 2s;
      -ms-animation-delay: 2s;
      animation-delay: 2s;
      color: #6b889d;
    }
    .rw-words-1 span:nth-child(3) {
      -webkit-animation-delay: 4s;
      -ms-animation-delay: 4s;
      animation-delay: 4s;
      color: #6b739d;
    }
    
    @-webkit-keyframes rotateWord {
      0% {
        opacity: 0;
      }
      2% {
        opacity: 0;
        -webkit-transform: translateY(-30px);
      }
      5% {
        opacity: 1;
        -webkit-transform: translateY(0px);
      }
      17% {
        opacity: 1;
        -webkit-transform: translateY(0px);
      }
      20% {
        opacity: 0;
        -webkit-transform: translateY(30px);
      }
      80% {
        opacity: 0;
      }
      100% {
        opacity: 0;
      }
    }
    @-ms-keyframes rotateWord {
      0% {
        opacity: 0;
      }
      2% {
        opacity: 0;
        -ms-transform: translateY(-30px);
      }
      5% {
        opacity: 1;
        -ms-transform: translateY(0px);
      }
      17% {
        opacity: 1;
        -ms-transform: translateY(0px);
      }
      20% {
        opacity: 0;
        -ms-transform: translateY(30px);
      }
      80% {
        opacity: 0;
      }
      100% {
        opacity: 0;
      }
    }
    @keyframes rotateWord {
      0% {
        opacity: 0;
      }
      2% {
        opacity: 0;
        -webkit-transform: translateY(-30px);
        transform: translateY(-30px);
      }
      5% {
        opacity: 1;
        -webkit-transform: translateY(0px);
        transform: translateY(0px);
      }
      17% {
        opacity: 1;
        -webkit-transform: translateY(0px);
        transform: translateY(0px);
      }
      20% {
        opacity: 0;
        -webkit-transform: translateY(30px);
        transform: translateY(30px);
      }
      80% {
        opacity: 0;
      }
      100% {
        opacity: 0;
      }
    }
    @media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
      .rw-sentence {
        font-size: 18px;
      }
    }
    @media screen and (max-width: 320px) {
      .rw-sentence {
        font-size: 9px;
      }
    }

/* stuff below added by Shomz */

.rw-words-1 span#last {
      -webkit-animation: rotateLastWord 8s 1 forwards 6s;
      -ms-animation: rotateLastWord 8s 1 forwards 6s;
      animation: rotateLastWord 8s 1 forwards 6s;
    }

@keyframes rotateLastWord {
      0% {
        opacity: 0;
      }
      2% {
        opacity: 0;
        -webkit-transform: translateY(-30px);
        transform: translateY(-30px);
      }
      5% {
        opacity: 1;
        -webkit-transform: translateY(0px);
        transform: translateY(0px);
      }
      17% {
        opacity: 1;
        -webkit-transform: translateY(0px);
        transform: translateY(0px);
      }
      100% {opacity: 1}
  }
```

```html
<section class="rw-wrapper">
  <h2 class="rw-sentence">
      <span>Test</span>
      <div class="rw-words rw-words-1">
       <span>one</span>
       <span>two</span>
       <span>three</span>
       <span id="last">four</span>
      </div>
     </h2>
</section>
```

Comment: You're welcome! Btw. I used a custom id so you can see the difference more easily, but you can still achieve the same results using the nth-child, like you originally did, just make sure you assign that other animation to the last element.